# OnControllerColliderHit triggering too many times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm wrote this script to decrease the players life and move them back to their original point on contact with certain objects, but I'm finding that it will trigger anywhere from 1 to 4 times per collision taking lives from 3 down to -1.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HitCar : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int lives = 3;

    void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.name == "utd_car1")
        {
            Destroy(col.gameObject);
            lives--;
            if(lives <= 0)
            {
                Application.LoadLevel("LoseScreen");
            }
            else
            {
                var player = GameObject.Find("3rd Person Controller");
                player.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 2, -26); 
            }
        }
    }

    void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level) 
    {
        lives = 3;
    }
}
```

Any way to prevent it from triggering more than once per collision would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnControllerColliderHit` is used when you want to hit something a few times, preferably to move it.

You can switch to this code:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) 
{
    if(col.gameObject.name == "utd_car1")
    {  
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason I can't get that function to trigger, which is why I went with OnControllerColliderHit originally. Thank you though.

Comment: @fenriskiba Take a look at the picture I posted on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009055/is-there-a-way-two-make-two-trigger-gameobjects-collide/27010330#27010330   it is a table that will teach you how to make things collide with each other.